# Create a line with text on the left border and right border

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to create a line at the end of a document which will just display a name on the left and the date on the right. I've attached an example.

I've considered using tables, but that seems like overkill for something like that and I couldn't come up with decent search terms to define my problem.

How could I recreate such a line?

[image: Example]

Edit: The solution should be working as well, if the name would be substituted with a image.

Comment: `\noindent Name Name \hfill Date`.  You may also need a `\vspace{<length>}` prior to it, if extra vertical space is required.

Comment: thank you. If you create an answer with that, I'll mark it solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in my comment to the OP, the use of `\hfill` provides infinitely stretchable glue that can push the surrounding material up against opposite margins.  The `\noindent` is needed to avoid a leading paragraph indentation.  Finally, I added a leading `\vspace{\baselineskip}` to provide a blank line before the desired name-date line.

Werner rightly notes in a comment that `\nobreak` may also be needed if the pagination would place the closing line on its own separate page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent Name Name \hfill Date
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...might need a `\nobreak` if this happens around the page boundary.